# Force scrollbar to classic style when overlay scrollbars are enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Browsers recently started rolling out overlay scrollbars, replacing the classic scrollbar style, which is always visible, with a scrollbar that only appears while scrolling.

[image: difference between overlay scrollbars and classic layout]

On macos this feature can be enabled by setting `system preferences / general / show scroll bars` to `when scrolling`.

**Is it possible to disable the overlay scrollbar and forcibly show the classic style at all times as-if the feature was disabled system-wide?**

While it is possible to force it to appear by setting custom styles for it, i.e. using `-webkit-scrollbar` on the element the scrollbar still does not behave as normal since it does not have a width, causing content to flow under it. It also changes the style of the scrollbars when overlay scrollbars are disabled which makes them inconsistent with the design of other scrollbars that may appear on the website.